# JavaFX Collision detection between Objects that have different parents

Tags: java, javafx

I have two panes: paneA and paneB, paneA contains objectA, and paneB contains objectB. However paneA also contains paneB. How can I detect the collision between ObjectA and ObjectB when they have different parents?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
Pane paneA = new Pane();
Pane paneB = new Pane();

Rectangle objectA = new Rectangle(50,30);
Rectangle objectB = new Rectangle(80,40);

paneB.getChildren().add(objectB);
paneA.getChildren().addAll(objectA, paneB);

if(objectA.getBoundsInParent().intersects(objectB.getBoundsInParent()) {
    collision = true;
}
```

Comment: There are methods in class [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScene-javafx.geometry.Bounds-) that are able to transform local coordinates to scene coordinates. Like `localToScene(Bounds localBounds)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem

You want to check for intersection of Shapes (or subtypes of Shape).

#### Solution

There is a already available static method in class Shape called intersect.

#### Example

The following example will show two rectangles that intersect. With the values from setX and setY you be able to move them until they not intersect. The Bounds will be displayed as Rectangles. Only when the objects intersect, the method `intersect(shape1, shape2)` will return a Shape with bounds width greater than 0.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CollisionDetection extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label label = new Label();
        Group groupA = new Group();
        Group groupB = new Group();

        Rectangle objectA = new Rectangle(50, 30);
        objectA.setFill(Paint.valueOf("red"));
        objectA.setX(100);
        objectA.setY(100);
        objectA.setRotate(10);
        objectA.setSmooth(true);

        Rectangle objectB = new Rectangle(80, 40);
        objectB.setFill(Paint.valueOf("blue"));
        objectB.setRotate(-10);
        objectB.setX(115);
        objectB.setY(50);        

        groupB.getChildren().add(objectB);
        groupA.getChildren().addAll(objectA,groupB);

        groupA.getChildren().add(createBoundsRectangle(objectA.getBoundsInParent()));
        groupA.getChildren().add(createBoundsRectangle(objectB.getBoundsInParent()));

        Shape intersect = Shape.intersect(objectA, objectB);

        if (intersect.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() > 0) {
            label.setText("ObjectA intersects ObjectB");
        } else {
            label.setText("ObjectA does not intersect ObjectB");
        }

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(groupA);
        root.setBottom(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);        

        primaryStage.setTitle("Collision Detection");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Rectangle createBoundsRectangle(Bounds bounds) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();       

        rect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rect.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));
        rect.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        rect.setStrokeWidth(3);

        rect.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        rect.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        rect.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        rect.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
        return rect;
      }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }  
}
```

#### Working Application with no intersection (even if bounds intersect)

[image: No Intersection]

#### Working Application with intersection

[image: Intersection]

Comment: This is a great solution!

Comment: Wouldn't this be a bit inaccurate to due the rotations? The bounds would not cover the object exactly.

Comment: @NwDev See https://gist.github.com/nhooyr/8332f0fd4127c16c4cb1785b991495c9 for an example of how this does not work accurately for rotated rectangles.

https://i.imgur.com/JZVHVOo.png

Comment: @NwDev Yes, I'm on javafx.runtime.version: 9.0.1+11

Comment: @NwDev According to the docs, is this not the expected behaviour? boundsInParent does not follow the transformations and boundsInParents is equivalent here to converting the local bounds to the bounds in the scene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163578/discussion-between-nhooyr-and-nwdev).